# why does this .pop(0) work like this

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def f(x, y):
   x.append(x.pop(0))
   x.append(y[0])
   return x

a = [4,5]
b = [1,2,3]
w = f(a,b) + f(a,b)
```

w turns out to be [4,1,5,1,4,1,5,1] However if I manually go through the code (in my head), I get [5,4,1,4,1,5,1]

Why is this?

f(a,b) = [5,4,1] right?, so then a would be = [5,4,1] and b = [1,2,3].

So then f(a,b) = [4,1,5,1] which would be:
[5,4,1] + [4,1,5,1]  = [5,4,1,4,1,5,1] NOT [4,1,5,1,4,1,5,1]

Why does the code change this? What am I doing wrong when trying to run through the code myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both calls return the *same* list, namely the object bound to `a`, resulting in the second returned value (which is still the object bound to `a`) being added to *itself*. The function only *mutates* the list, never replaces it.

Comment: but then wouldnt my answer be right? f(a,b) = [5,4,1], I checked it in python... why is it [4,1,5 ....] ...?

Comment: @Ghozt: Because you're calling `f()` *twice*.

Comment: @aIKid: It really isn't. It's still the same list regardless of when you returned it.

Comment: So it runs them at the same time? So to work this out in my head I go through the first function, then the second, then make the first function equal to the second, then add them?

Comment: @Ghozt: You don't need to "make it equal", it is the *same list both times*. The contents each time are irrelevant. Try saving the return values, mutating `a`, and then examining the saved values.

Comment: but but... its not the same each time! How can it be? Seriously, run it in python but with w = f(a,b) and you get [5,4,1]. then if you make w = f(a,b) + f(a,b) then it is [4,1,5,1,4,1,5,1]..... #confused

Comment: Yes i understand that it is the same list. However, the first call results in `[5, 4, 1]` and the second in `[4, 1, 5, 1]`. Why would they add to `[4, 1, 5, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1]`

Comment: @Ghozt: And then examine `a`.

Comment: I've checked that the `id` of `x` is the same.

Comment: @aIKid: Again, it doesn't matter *when* you returned the list, it is still the same list. Further mutations mutate it further.

Comment: I haven't really understand.. I do understand that this is the same list returned. But when i write `f(a, b) + f(a, b)` shouldn't it be the same as `[5, 4, 1] + [4, 1, 5, 1]`?

Comment: @aIKid: No. It should be the same as `a + a`, since the object bound to `a` is what is eventually returned.

Comment: The order of execution is "the first f(a,b)", "the second f(a,b)", then the "f(a,b) + f(a,b)". Now, the confusion is there because when you return a list, it actually returns the address of the list. So "the first f(a,b)" will return "address of x", so is "the second f(a,b)". Lastly, when they're added, you're adding x (which has been modified twice into `[4,1,5,1]`) into itself. So the result is `[4,1,5,1,4,1,5,1]`

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Maybe you should add more details to your answer. I didn't get it until I read the whole comment list.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that your code both changes the original list and although returns a reference to it. When you invoke *f* for the second time (never use one-letter names !!!) you change the result of the original call as well. Let's do it by stages:

```
n [53]: a1 = f(a,b)

In [54]: a
Out[54]: [5, 4, 1]

In [55]: a2 = f(a,b)

In [56]: a2
Out[56]: [4, 1, 5, 1]

In [57]: a
Out[57]: [4, 1, 5, 1]
```

This illustrates my point (function *id* returns reference to an object)

```
In [77]: id(a)
Out[77]: 145114860

In [78]: id (f(a,b))
Out[78]: 145114860
```

As you may see, your function has a side effect. If you rewrite it like this

```
def f(x, y):
    x.append(x.pop(0))
    x.append(y[0])
    return copy(x)
```

The second call will not on impact the result of the first call -

```
In [74]: id(a)
Out[74]: 145114860

In [75]: id (f(a,b))
Out[75]: 145113356
```

and the result will be [5, 4, 1, 4, 1, 5, 1]

Answer (score 0):

> f(a,b) = [5,4,1] right?, so then a would be = [5,4,1] and b = [1,2,3].

All correct.  However.  If you look at what `f` is doing, it is just returning the mutated `x` (i.e. mutating `a`).  So do it *twice*:

```
f(a,b)
Out[40]: [5, 4, 1]

a
Out[41]: [5, 4, 1]

f(a,b)
Out[42]: [4, 1, 5, 1]

a
Out[43]: [4, 1, 5, 1]
```

then concatenate that with itself.  That's what `w` is: just `a + a`, after having mutated `a` twice.